# Getting different instances of vue-awesome-swiper in WebStorm and PhpStorm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, phpstorm, webstorm, swiper.js

I have been using vue-awesome-swiper on a WebStorm project and using the functions it offers. I have recently moved my project to PhpStorm and I found that many of the functions no longer work.

After using `console.log(mySwiper)` to check why this is happening, I discovered that I am receiving different instances of the object, and that they hold different function names. For example, in WebStorm the swiper is named 'Swiper' and it contains an object named 'autoplay' that contains several functions related to autoplay. However, through PhpStrom the swiper is named 'i', and does not contain 'autoplay'. Instead, there is a boolean named 'autoplaying' that does not exist in WebStorm.

Both WebStorm and PhpStorm projects include the same version of `swiper` (4.3.3), of `vue-awesome-swiper` (3.1.3), and of `Vue` (2.3.4).

The documentation of vue-awesome-swiper only refers to the functinality that I get while using WebStorm, which makes it impossible to use the swiper on PhpStorm.

Please help me figure out this strange behavior. thanks!

Comment: vue.js support in PhpStorm and WebStorm is exactly the same (built from same sources). Please can you elaborate on the issue? do you have some problems with non-working functions in runtime, or the problem only concerns to working in editor (code completion, etc.)? Code snippets/screenshots would be helpful

Comment: The problem is during runtime. Many functions stopped working, for instance `delay` between slides in autoplay, `slidesPerGroup`, and `disableOnInteraction`. I logged the `Swiper` object and found that it is not identical in WebStorm and PhpStorm. The mentioned functions do not exist in PhpStorm.

Comment: this must be a problem with your project. Neither webstorm nor PhpStorm have these functions,etc. bundled. What you see in runtime only depends on your application configuration and has absolutely no relation to the IDE you are using for app development